# r-base-core build on ubuntu 10.04 failing because of missing libjpeg8 package

Tags: r, ubuntu-10.04, package-managers

So the libjpeg8 package on 10.04 has reached EOL.

Is there a way to locate and install the legacy package for this?

```
$ sudo apt-get install r-base-core
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  r-base-core: Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15) but 2.11.1-0ubuntu7.13 is to be installed
               Depends: libjpeg8 (>= 8c) but it is not installable
               Depends: liblzma5 (>= 5.1.1alpha+20110809) but it is not installable
               Depends: libpcre3 (>= 8.10) but 7.8-3build1 is to be installed
               Recommends: r-recommended but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

Comment: Are you on the server version of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following commands.

`sudo apt-get install -f`
This would install any dependencies that your previous installs missed.

If that doesn't help, please refer to the following link:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies